# Help with persistence

Tags: wireless, vlc, persistence

Every time I get to a certain stage of installing either the wireless drivers, or FBReader, or VLC when my system hangs or crashes. ?Then on reboot, I am asked for a password by Ubuntu, which I don't have...

After which I need to restart with a new install using unebootin...

Please can someone help me do the following with no errors:

1) get all updates and upgrades with no 'PACKAGE OPERTATION FAILED' errors

2) get wireless drivers installed and working

3) get FBReader and VLC installed and working.

btw, I am still a beginner just getting the hang of the Terminal

I replaced my 2 year old Kingston Data Traveller USB Stick yesterday with a new Sandisk Cruze Blade in case that was the issue

thaks
Philip

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with the live CD and installing with unetbootin. You would have to remaster the live CD. You would extract the file system, do the updates, install the drivers, then repackage the iso.

Using persistence, with the / , works if you install or upgrade a few packages, but with a large update I find it often fails (as has been your experience). Better to use a persistent /home (make a file on the usb called `home-rw` ).

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

If all that is too much hassle, do a standard install to the flash drive (not unetbootin, install ubuntu to the flash drive).

Answer (score 0):

Updating a persistent install will quickly fill a flash drive, once filled it will not boot until the casper-rw file is reduced in size.
You can not upgrade a persistent flash drive since the kernel is part of a read only file.

You should be able to get wireless, FBReader and VLC working on a persistent system, if you forget the update.

If you need the latest updates and upgrades you can do a Full install to an 8GB or larger flash as Bodi.Zazen suggests.

If you absolutely need to update a persistent flash drive, you can use casper-rw and home-rw ext2 partitions that are not limited to the 4GB size FAT32 files are.